# how to identify this sequence and find out its next terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here's the sequence:
*2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 17, …*

OEIS succeeded in identifying the sequence, but I'm unable to understand the pattern behind it.
https://oeis.org/A007918
Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Smallest prime $\geqslant n$, starting at $0$?

Comment: It's clearly explained as the least prime larger than n, so for example, $a_{10} = 11$, as 11 is the smallest prime number larger than 10

Comment: The OEIS link you provide says " Least prime >= n" which works if you think of the terms as numbered 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: @fcortes Larger than or equal to*